# IEnumerable to List performance issue

Tags: c#, performance, linq, ienumerable

I'd been through several posts at SO, but couldn't find out solution (for this specific).
I have some complex Linq query, that returns few *thousands* of rows. I'm using `IEnumerable` for result. But later, I need to iterate through each row, to perform some operation. for this purpose, I convert it using a call to `ToList()`. But this (I believe) is killing the performance, and *times out*. Any suggestion/guidance for optimization? You may correct me if I'm missing something. (I'm new to performance issues)

Here's my code:

```
IEnumerable<someModel> results = null;

results = from x in tableX ..... select xyz;
//some complex query, returning few thousands of rows.

//now converting to list:
List<someModel> MYresults = results.ToList();
number_of_records = MYresults.Distinct(new myComparer()).Count();

//row operation that I need to perform:
if(condition)
{
    foreach(someModel m in MYresults)
    {
        m.property = m.property + someOperations();
    }
}

if(somecondition)
{
    return MYresults.Distinct(new someComparer()).ToList();
}
else
    return MYresults.Distinct(new someComparer()).Skip(x).Take(y).ToList();
```

Comment: Why do you need to convert it to list to iterate through items? You should be able to iterate through `results` just as well

Comment: You would really need to show the full query because that would be were the issue is if the `ToList` is timing out.

Comment: @Zeeshan, but anyway calling `ToList` should not be that much different then. When you call `ToList` it's just the point where your LINQ is executed. Maybe you can optimize your LINQ but for that you need to show it.

Comment: How about measuring where the time is _actually_ being spent?

Answer (score 2):

The `results` variable does not contain thousands of rows... just a query.

```
results = from x in tableX ..... select xyz;  // just a query, no data yet
```

You're not actually retrieving any records until you call `ToList()`. The slowness could be the complexity of the query, or the number of records.. or both.

```
List<someModel> MYresults = results.ToList();  // get data
```

Since you're then doing a `Distinct()` on the data to trim out some records, I'd take a look at merging the following line into your original LINQ statement, so you don't even pull those records over in the first place. *(This may not work as-is, if the code in `someComparer` can't be translated into valid SQL.)*

```
results = from x in tableX ..... select xyz;

return results.Distinct(new someComparer()).ToList();
```